# foreach js reformat data

Tags: javascript, foreach

i am creating a rest API and i get data from one of my request
but i want to parse them

i try to create a foreach loop but a get in every line the same result 
there
is a sample of my data

```
      result = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "UserID": 2,
        "idFriend": 3,
        "status": "pending",
        "UserId": 2,
        "User": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "toto@gmail.com",
            "username": "tetar",
            "isAdmin": false,
            "isOut": false,
            "bio": null,
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "UserID": 2,
        "idFriend": 1,
        "status": "pending",
        "UserId": 2,
        "User": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "toto@gmail.com",
            "username": "tetar",
            "isAdmin": false,
            "isOut": false,
            "bio": null,
        }
    },
]
```

and i want to get my data modifed like

```
`result = [{
  "id"= 1,
  "User": {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "toto@gmail.com",
        "username": "tetar"
     }
  },
  {
  "id"= 2,
  "User": {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "titi@gmail.com",
        "username": "tetar"
     }
    }
  }]`
```

do you know how can i do it ? 
thx a lot

Comment: Where's your code? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service....or a *"how to"* tutorial service. You are expected to show your attempts to solve issues yourself and people help you fix **your code**

Comment: i just past 2 hour to deal with this issue and in 3 min in Stackoverflow someone give me the solution. i think the purpose of this web site is to help each other.

Comment: No...that is not how it is supposed to work. Take some time to read [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a mapping function.

```
const newResult = [];

result.forEach((r) => {
  newResult.push({
    id: r.id,
    user: {
      id: r.User.id,
      email: r.User.email,
      username: r.User.username
    }
  });
});

console.log(newResult);
```

I am pretty sure there are better cleaner and more performant ways to do this. I recommend using lodash map function:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.map:

```js
result = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "UserID": 2,
        "idFriend": 3,
        "status": "pending",
        "UserId": 2,
        "User": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "toto@gmail.com",
            "username": "tetar",
            "isAdmin": false,
            "isOut": false,
            "bio": null,
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "UserID": 2,
        "idFriend": 1,
        "status": "pending",
        "UserId": 2,
        "User": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "toto@gmail.com",
            "username": "tetar",
            "isAdmin": false,
            "isOut": false,
            "bio": null,
        }
    },
]
let out = result.map(el=>{return {id: el.id, User:{id: el.User.id, email: el.User.email, username:el.User.username}}});
console.log(out);
```